# trigger beginElement with snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg, smil

Is it possible to launch the animation of an `<animate>` tag with snap.svg in the same way you do with `.beginElement()`?

And if so, would the animation work in browsers that do not support SMIL?

Comment: If the UA does not support SMIL then you'll need a plugin such as fakeSmile. What works depends on what plugin you choose.

Comment: I've always found beginElement hit and miss for support, so never found it to be worth it. If you are using Snap anyway, I would just use their animation methods.